# Linear transformation and matrix basis

Tags: matrices

Consider the linear transformation $T:M_{2x2}(\mathbb{R}) \rightarrow M_{2x2}(\mathbb{R})$ defined by $T(A)= A^T$.
Consider the basis $B$ of $M_{2x2}(\mathbb{R})$, defined by:

$$B=\left(\begin{bmatrix}1&0\\0&0\end{bmatrix},\begin{bmatrix}0&0\\0&1\end{bmatrix},\begin{bmatrix}0&1\\1&0\end{bmatrix},\begin{bmatrix}1&0\\1&0\end{bmatrix}\right)$$

What is the matrix $M=(T; B, B)$ that represents $T$ in this basis?
I 've been around this exercise all weekend and seem to be going around in circles. Woud really appreciate some help on this.
Thanks.

Comment: What have you tried? Like applying $T$ to each of your basis vectors in turn, and expressing the result as a linear combination of the basis vectors? It will be useful to *name* the basis vectors, like $e_1$, $e_2$, $e_3$, $e_4$ or whatever naming scheme you fancy.

Comment: What I find difficult is that my vectors are all 2x2 matrices and I don't know where to go from there. Shuld I transpose these vectors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write you basis as  $b_1, \cdots, b_4$. Then $T(b_1)=b_1=1\cdot b_1 +0\cdot b_2+0\cdot b_3+0\cdot b_4$. Similarly, $T(b_2)=b_2, T(b_3)=b_3$. $T(b_4)=2\cdot b_1+0\cdot b_2+1\cdot b_3+(-1)\cdot b_4$. Hence the matrix for T is $$\left(
  \begin{array}{cccc}
    1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
    0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
    0 & 0 & 1 & 1 \\
    2 & 0 & 1 & -1
  \end{array}
\right)$$

Answer (score 2):

Note that, if $A=\left(
  \begin{array}{cc}
    a & b \\
    c & d \\
  \end{array}
\right)$, then $T(A)=T\left(
  \begin{array}{cc}
    a & b \\
    c & d \\
  \end{array}
\right)=\left(
  \begin{array}{cc}
    a & b \\
    c & d \\
  \end{array}
\right)^{t}=\left(
  \begin{array}{cc}
    a & c \\
    b & d \\
  \end{array}
\right)$

Comment: How do I go from here to matrix M? I have four 2x2 basis matrices and in the end I will have a 4x4 matrix after applying the transformation.

Comment: The transformation takes 2x2 matrices on 2x2 matrices. The transformation matrix is 4x4.

Comment: If I transpose the 2x2 matrices on B, I get B' with the corresponding transposed matrices. My difficulty is in going from there to calculate M.

Comment: Let B = {u, v, w, z}. Calculate T (u) and then write T (u) = au + bv + cw + dz.  Determine a, b​​, c and d. The vector (a, b, c, d) is the first column of M. Repeat for v, to find the second column of M. Etc.